# Docker Python library cannot properly login into AWS ECR

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker

I wrote a Python script to pull images from AWS ECR to an Ubuntu instance. On this instance, I run docker commands with `sudo` as Docker is not setup as a non-root user.

I do use `sudo` when invoking the script. What I find is if I am currently logged into AWS ECR first and then I run the script, it works as expected. However, if I am not logged in, and the auth token is expired, it appears that `docker login` works, but when I try and pull I get a message indicating that the "repository does not exist or my require 'docker login'".

Examining logs, it verifies this with

> Feb 15 06:00:38 ubuntu-xenial dockerd[1388]:
>   time="2019-02-15T06:00:38.832827449Z" level=error msg="Not continuing
>   with pull after error: denied: Your Authorization Token has expired.
>   Please run 'aws ecr get-login --no-include-email' to fetch a new one."

```
def log_into_aws_ecr(docker_client, region):
    # To do, set region
    ecr_client = boto3.client('ecr', region_name=region)

    # Get all repos
    response = ecr_client.describe_repositories()
    repo_names = []
    repositories = response.get('repositories', [])
    for repo in repositories:
        name = repo.get('repositoryName', '')
        if len(name):
            repo_names.append(name)
    token = ecr_client.get_authorization_token()
    username, password = base64.b64decode(token['authorizationData'][0]['authorizationToken']).decode('utf-8').split(":")
    registry_url = token['authorizationData'][0]['proxyEndpoint']
    login_results = docker_client.login(username, password, email='', registry=registry_url)

    prefix='https://'
    if registry_url.startswith(prefix):
        registry = registry_url[len(prefix):]
    else:
        registry = registry_url
    auth_config_payload = {'username': username, 'password': password }
    return ecr_client, repo_names, registry
```

Please note that this code is also being re-factored now, so there are some variables that are defined but not currently in use.

The supplied `docker_client` is obtained via the line

```
    docker_client = docker.from_env()
```

I've tried running as

`sudo -E ./myscript.py image`

But this doesn't work either. I have a variant of this using a bash script and that works fine.

Output for the `docker_client.login` looks like

> Looking for auth entry for 'ABCXYZ.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
>   Found 'ABCXYZ.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com'

And if I dump the response, it looks like this.

> {'password': 'PASSWORD HERE', 'email': None, 'username': 'AWS',
>   'serveraddress': 'ABCXYZ.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com'}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I'm not quite sure if this is fully correct, however, based on some experimentation over the last few days, it does work. I also did open up an issue on the docker-py GitHub repo, but at least as of now, no one has chimed in.

https://github.com/docker/docker-py/issues/2256

In a nutshell, which I've listed in the link, here is what I came up with:

Okay, I ran some experiments the last few days. Had to deal with the 12 hour AWS ECR ticket so it took a little longer to do.

It does seem that there is an issue with docker-py.

> Based on my findings, I can either use `boto3` or run a sub-process
>   calling the command line to `aws ecr`. However the only permutation
>   that seems to work with the following steps.
>
> 1. use a sub-process to perform the `docker login`. This will result in the `config.json` file being updated (not sure if this has any
>      relevance at all or not).
> 2. Create the docker client via `docker_client = docker.from_env()`. I have found doing this prior to the sub-process results in it not
>      working properly (unless you have an already valid `config.json`
> 3. Then call `docker_client.login(username=username, password=password, registry=registry_url)`
>
> Whether or not this is expected or not or if I'm doing something
>   wrong, I don't know. This is what I've come up with as steps that
>   work.

Answer (score 0):

`get_authorization_token` returns username and password but it is base encoded. See https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/develop/awscli/customizations/ecr.py#L53:L54

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I invoke the command line I do indeed include the `--no-include-email` flag for `get-login`. However, I could not find the equivalent for boto3. BTW, if you look at the code, I base64 decode the response. And by copying those 2 lines, you mean into the aws cli package?

Comment: Can you attach the output of both `aws ecr get-login` and `get_authorization_token` ?

Comment: I don't think a comparison of the two outputs matter. What modified my code so that I can get the auth token either by running `aws ecr get-login` as a subprocess or by calling `get_authorization_token`. I can also into docker either by subprocess or by calling the docker python's `login`. What I have discovered so far, but need some more testing, is that it looks like the issue isn't AWS rather docker-py. Right now it appears that any combo of getting the auth token works. But overall success is dictated by whether or not I use the subprocess or not.